# Specificity issue with "composes" keyword using CSS Modules and React

Tags: css, webpack, css-loader, css-modules

I'm having CSS specificity/import order issues when trying to use CSS modules "composes" keyword.

**File structure:**

```
|_ MyComponent.jsx
|_ MyComponent.scss
|_ utilities.scss
```

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './MyComponent.scss';

const MyComponent = ({ error }) => {
  const classes = classnames(
    styles.root,
    {
      [styles.error]: error
    }
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

**MyComponent.scss**

```
.root {
  color: #333;
}

.error {
  composes: red from './utilities.scss';
}
```

**utilities.scss**

```
.red {
   color: red;
}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, the `.red` class is not applying because of an import order issue. Is there a way around this without resorting to something like `!important`?

[image]

Note: I'm using CSS modules with webpack + scss loader.

Comment: Hi @cusejuice! I have the same issue. Did you find a solution except `!important`?